# Open JPA - @TableGenerator with composite primary key for auxiliary table

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, openjpa

I have below entity which uses `TABLE` strategy for its id generation and works perfectly fine.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test_Table")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "AUX_TABLE", pkColumnName = "KEY_NAME", valueColumnName = "KEY_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "someValue", allocationSize = 10)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 20)
    private long someId;

    // few other properties and getter / setter
}
```

Below is table structure of `AUX_TABLE` used to fetch the id values

> DOMAIN varchar2(4) NOT NULL,
>      
> KEY_NAME varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
>      
> KEY_VALUE decimal(2) NOT NULL,
>      
> CONSTRAINT AUX_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (DOMAIN,KEY_NAME)

As `AUX_TABLE` has *composite primary key* comprising of `DOMAIN` and `KEY_NAME`; I am unable to figure how to specify them in `pkColumnName` and their respective value in `pkColumnValue` attribute of `@TableGenerator`.

I tried `pkColumnName = "DOMAIN,KEY_NAME"` but it failed with following exception

> Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: ORA-00904: "DOMAIN,KEY_NAME": invalid identifier
>    {prepstmnt 9864699 SELECT KEY_VALUE FROM AUX_TABLE WHERE "DOMAIN,KEY_NAME" = ? FOR UPDATE [params=?]} [code=904, state=42000]
>       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:203)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1118)

The [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html) for `@TableGenerator` has no mention for this particular case.

I am using *Open JPA 2.3.0* with *JDK 1.7.0_45*

Comment: In the given table structure am not seeing any column name that you 're trying to use as primary key. Make sure once whether you have defined columns with appropriate names.

Comment: @ViswanathD I have now added the primary key in the question (*it is already present in my DB*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. TableGenerator has a simple key/value structure.